# Leading Zeros to organise project folders within columns

Tags: sharepoint-online, column-formatting

Hi I am a complete newbie and I want to organise the Projects by JobPac numbers which start with leading Zeros - 0001, 0002 is there some way I can do this? Or would it be best to ask the JobPac team to renumber and drop leading zeros? I found an answer from 2014 which suggested this-  concat(substring('00', 1, 3 - string-length(field)), field)
However I tried but it didn't work displayed 5 not 0005.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to add 3 leading zeros, JSON formatting will help you do that.

[How to start using JSON formatting.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#get-started-with-column-formatting)

**A bit more explanation**: The JSON I provide simple add 3 leading zeros on the original pac number. So no need to worry about the input. If user enters, say '11', then in the list you will see '00011'.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "=('000'+'@currentField')"
}
```

The original code number is M123456789.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could create a calculated column that references the JobPac number field and use something like this for the formula:

```
=Text([jobPacField],"0000")
```

[image]

**Update**

If you're having difficulty with the formula, it might be easier to double click on the column from the "Insert Column" box.

[image]

Another thing that might cause an issue is pasting the double quotes from this website. Perhaps try typing the formula instead of copying & pasting?

Comment: Updated answer with some troubleshooting suggestions

Comment: Thanks I have done that and typed it, changed it, added from insert column =Text(intField,"000") and I've tried =Text[intField,"000"] and i get - The formula contains a syntax error or is not supported. any ideas please?

Comment: What type is your [intField] column? Mine is a Number type. From what I can tell, that formula should definitely work for both "Number" and "Single line of text" columns.

Comment: yup it's a Number type. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. I think I have set up the column I want the new one to calculate from wrong as it is green in the Settings menu.

Answer (score 0):

You want the new padStart operator

From
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/formatting-syntax-reference

padStart: pads the current string with another string until the resulting string reaches the given length. The padding is applied from the start of the current string.

```
"txtContent":"=padStart('DogFood', 10, 'A')" results in AAADogFood
"txtContent":"=padStart('DogFood', 10, 'AB')" results in ABADogFood
"txtContent":"=padStart('DogFood', 5, 'A')" results in DogFood
```

The way I have implemented it on a number column is as below:

```
{
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "div",
   "txtContent":"=padStart(toString(@currentField), 4, '0')"
}
```